# How disable attribute in second site

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, multistore

I have configured 2 sites.
Have attribute named 'label'.

**How to remove it on second site and leave it on default (first) site?**

Comment: "Remove" from which area?

Comment: From information about goods, from layer navigation, compare. Enable this attribute on first site and disable on second.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Magento, and I don't think a customization is a great idea. The problem lies in the data-structure: attribute-sets and attributes don't have a store- or website-ID, so their existence is always "global". Database-tables to inspect would be `eav_attribute` and `catalog_product_attribute`.

You could alter the database tables and add a `website_id` column, then override the collection (or use an observer) and always filter for the current website; however, I have no idea how the whole EAV-thing would react to this.

The best solution imho would be to create two attributes: `label_website_one` and `label_website_two`. If the values of an attribute are empty for a website, it won't appear in layered navigation. You could then override the template-files for compare, additional product information, maybe cart and so on to hide attributes without a value.